# Experimenting with a basic throttled multithread function; but code breaking at some point

Tags: python, multithreading, jupyter

My main objective is to build a multi threaded google API based program, where I need to make 1000s of API calls and hence I want to avoid hitting the spam rate limit (max 10 calls per second).  I couldn't get the throttling mechanism in that program to work, so I went back to building a basic mechanism for getting that correct first.

Now below is that program, but the only output I get is:

***Creating Queue,  20***

anaconda/jupyter notebook on windows pc.

So where is this code getting stuck? Any hints appreciated.

```
import time
from threading import Thread
import inspect
import queue

lastcalled = 0.000000999
logstring = ""
g_throttle_interval = 0.5 #seconds
maxQitems = 20
q = queue.Queue(maxQitems)

class OnlyForStaticMethod:
    @staticmethod
    def ThrottledMethod(inputx):
        global lastcalled, logstring
        try:
            currtime = time.time()
            logstring = logstring + "\n" + str(inputx) + " , Lastcalled, " + str(lastcalled) + ", and now, " + str(currtime)
            lastcalled = time.time()
            time.sleep(g_throttle_interval)
        except Exception as e:
            print ("Error1 , ", repr(e))
        return 1
    
def CalledByThread():
    while True:
        try:
            OnlyForStaticMethod.ThrottledMethod(q.get())
        except Exception as e:
            print ("Error2 , ", repr(e))            
    return 1
            
                
print ("Creating Queue, ", maxQitems)

try:
    for x in range(20):
        q.put(x)
    q.join()
except Exception as e:
    print ("Some exception here ", repr(e))
    sys.exit(1)

print ("Creating threads")

for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=CalledByThread)
    t.daemon = True
    #print (i, " Thread starting")
    t.start()

print ("\n *** \n Program Over, log below \n")
print (logstring)
```

Comment: Think about what q.join() is going to do and you'll have your answer

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your app is stuck on `q.join()`

As per documentation:

> **Queue.join()**
>
> Blocks until all items in the queue have been gotten and processed.
>
> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the
> queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls
> **task_done()** to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it
> is complete. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join()
> unblocks.

That's why you never initialize your Threads, no work gets done and it simply hangs around forever, since the count of unfinished tasks never decreases.

One way to do this is to call q.task_done() in your threads consuming the queue. You can do this in ThrottledMethod or CalledByThread whenever you deem the task is finished.

For instance:

```
def CalledByThread():
    while True:
         i = q.get()
         if i is None:
             break:
         OnlyForStaticMethod.ThrottledMethod()
         q.task_done()
```

**But right now this wouldn't work,** because q.join() is blocking and at this point your program doesn't have any threads that know they should call a target, so the target (CalledByThread) neither gets a q nor could it set a q.task_done.

That's why you should change the order to something like this:

```
q = queue.Queue(maxQitems)
threads = []
    t = Thread(target=CalledByThread)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for x in range(20):
    q.put(x)
q.join()
```